# SSRS 2012 Text missing when exporting to pdf or excel

Tags: sql, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS (2012) .rdl main report that calls a subreport. This subreport is displaying a column which is a very long string.

If I call the subreport directly, this column displays the entirety of the text.

[image]

If I call the main report (which subsequently calls, among others, the afforementioned subreport), the preview in the SSRS page also shows the entire text as it's supposed to, but when I export it to .pdf or excel, all the text after the first line is missing (the first line of text is shown, and the rest of the space where the text should is just blank).

[image]

This issue does not occur when calling the subreport directly, but it does when I call the main report.

Furthermore, I have 2 environments with these reports installed, Production and Development, and the issue does not occur in Development, but it does in Production, and only if I call the main report!

I have already checked all the .rdl, .rsd and .dll files installed on both environments, and all of them are exact matches. The text itself, is the same for this column on both databases (I think). I have confirmed that `"Page Width >= Body Width + Left Margin + Right Margin"`, also I tried on the Report Properties changing the margins from cm to Inches and back to cm to get the margins rounded up by 4 or 5 decimal digits, none of it worked.

I have looked extensively for problems similar to mine, but none of them were properly answered. I have no idea what is causing this, but considering that the subreport works just fine, that the same main report works fine in Development, and that even on the preview of the Production environment all of the text is shown, I suspect it may have something to do with the exporting process. The browser used is always the same in all scenarios, IE11. The PDF is Acrobat Reader DC.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Can you delete the report on your production box and redeploy and see if that does anything magical. Is that long memo field using a different font and if so can you verify that the font is installed on the production server? As a sanity check, you may consider making sure the visibility on all report items is set to hidden=false and try to print again.

Comment: Also check the service packs/versions of SSRS in both environments, it could be a bug fix that's not been updated on your production server.

Comment: @RossBush The visibility on the report item is set to Hidden=False for this textbox. However, the font may be a different story. I will check this and let you know, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I have not checked the service packs or the versions. Will do it and let you know, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @AlanSchofield I am unsure if it's the right way to do it, but I checked the version and service pack on SQL Server Configuration, under SQL Server Reporting Services properties of the instance where it is installed: 
Version: 11.1.3000.0
Service Pack Level: 1

It's same on both environments :(

Comment: @RossBush The font is the same. I tested on Development environment with the same text I had on Production. Also, just to be safe, I checked on Notepad++ with the View in Hex plugin, to determine if there was a strange character on the text that might not be visible. No luck :( 

It would be odd that the subreport and the main report had different behaviours (on same environment) because of a specific font, since ultimately, it's always the subreport that handles the text.